# using -ms-filter with iinternet explorer 9

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am using visual studio 2008 to build a web application.css version is 2.1 and internet explorer version i have is ie9.with css 2.1 version opacity property is not there so i am using `-ms-filter` to make my code work in ie9.here is my code

```
.wait
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #E1FFFF;
    text-align: center;
    cursor:wait;
    opacity:0.5;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

but it is not working.pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

If you want opacity to work in all IE versions, the order should be:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  // second!
```

[Reffer Notes](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)

Comment: @shreesha if my answer helpful grateful by  Vote it. Thank you